# header and footer look terrible when I resize the browser window

Tags: html, css

I am having this issue where everything is aligned properly but when I resize the browser window it shows a scroll bar at the bottom to scroll horizontally ...when you scroll the header and footer are cut out and it looks really ugly.
any ideas on how to fix that please ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `#content` `div` has `width:1000px;`, whereas the header and footer are only set to `width: 100%`.

You can patch this up by adding `min-width: 1000px;` to your header and footer selectors, so that they won't be shrunk any further than the width of the page.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Your `#content` is causing the scroll because of `1000px width`

Answer (score 3):

you can try this css:

```
html, body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

and this css for header and footer and content div:

```
header, footer, #content{
min-width: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this to fix it

```
body {
   width:100%; 
   min-width: 1000px;
}
```

As your `#content <div>` width is `1000px;` and your header/footer are set to `100%;` which generally never prints out of the size of your **viewport** so you can use this to fix